# El adjetivo sordo

Tags: definiciones, literatura, diccionarios

I have a book called *Pasajes Literatura* by Bretz, Dvorak, Kirschner, & Kihyet. In it there is a passage from *La conciencia* by Ana María Matute. There is a part that says, "En efecto, allá afuera, Mariana oyó el redoble de la lluvia contra los maderos de la puerta. Una lluvia sorda, gruesa, anuncio de la tormenta próxima." I know sorda means 'deaf,' and I saw that the book gives a footnote translating the word as 'deafening'. Deafening in English means 'very loud' like loud to the point that it makes you go deaf. Is this a valid translation of the word sorda because when I look it up in the DLE of the Real Academia Española, I don't see a definition resembling something like 'really loud.' In fact, all of the definitions appear to me to mean 'really quiet.' Is 'deafening' a mistranslation or a valid translation? I know gruesa would mean something like 'heavy,' so maybe the combination of sorda with gruesa is what makes it deafening?

Link to the DLE: https://dle.rae.es/sordo?m=form

"callado, silencioso y sin ruido."
"que suena poco o sin timbre claro."

Comment: Good question. I have never seen "sordo" used meaning "deafening"... I am going to have to suggest the possibility that that footnote is wrong. I would interpret "lluvia sorda" as definition 3 on DLE (something like a "nondescript, featureless sound"). But maybe someone else knows something I don't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you spotted something that may come odd and confusing with the Spanish paragraph. But if the author intended to mean "deafening" for a noise `so loud as to make it impossible to hear anything else` the word to use would have been

> [ensordecedor, ra](https://dle.rae.es/ensordecedor?m=form)
>
> 1. adj. Que ensordece.
> 2. adj. Dicho de un ruido o de un sonido: Muy intenso.

Though it appears as the adjective `sorda` applied to the rain was deliberate —for it being a prelude of the near storm— the total expression lacks descriptive quality. I'm with you about the adjective 'gruesa' along (implying heavy/pesada) it makes it problematic leading to a bit of a dissonance; much so because of the word `redoble` (rumbling) when hitting the wooden door. It brings an association that is not that quiet.

In spite of that I would say that:

- the author meant `sorda` (in a not totally fit conjunction with `gruesa`, but which is something that may happen sometimes when big drops of rain fall scattered and far from each other)
- and, —most likely because of that non happy or intuitive wording— the translation was not accurate about using `deafening`

Comment: That first bullet point makes a lot of sense, and I think you're right. I feel like I can hear it now: a heavy raindrop, a pause, and then another heavy raindrop all sort of scattered. Perfect! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Wachu I’m not a native speaker either, but I would think of it as almost the opposite of that: “Mariana heard the rumble of rain against the wooden door: a dull, heavy rain, portending the coming thunderstorm” – I’m imagining rain coming down hard and a thick wooden door which lends a dull, rumbling constancy to the sound of the raindrops, making them sound almost like thunder rolling in the distance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Interesting. I'm not too sure I know what "dull rain" would be. I wouldn't think to describe rain as dull.

Comment: @Wachu Think of how it sounds when rain falls on a tin roof – rapid, high-pitched series of clearly distinguishable individual pit-pats. Now think of it hitting a thick, solid oak door – the individual drops sort of melt into each other, and the whole thing sounds more like a rumble than a series of individual sounds. That’s what I’d describe as a dull, heavy sound, synecdochically applied to the rain itself here, but referring really to the sound.